# Couldn't establish an ajax connection using jQuery, form automatically submits?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, form-submit

I am quite a newbie on Jquery and just faced a problem that I'm not able to get over.

I, simply, have an HTML form with a few elements on a page. I want to validate the form values upon clicking the submit button, and then insert some of the form values to a db using JQuery. Right after the insert process completed successfully, I want the form to be submitted naturally.

I made the validation work, and get all to values successfully from the form, but I am not able to connect to the PHP page. I have two pages.

Here is the JQuery code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#odeme").submit(function() {


                $('#ok').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("#ok").after('<span id="info" style="font-size:8pt;color:green;padding-left:5px;"><img align="absmiddle" src="loading.gif" border="0" /> &nbsp; Ödemeniz Yapılıyor</span>');

                //değişkenler

                var jad = $("#ad").val().length;  
                var jsoyad = $("#soyad").val().length;  
                var jadres = $("#adres").val().length;  
                var jeposta = $("#eposta").val().length;
                var isEposta = $("#eposta").val();
                var epostaReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;  
                var jsehir = $("#sehir").val(); 
                var jtaksit = $("#taksit").val();  
                var jkartisim = $("#kartisim").val().length;  
                var jkartno = $("#kartno").val().length;
                var jkartay = $("#kartay").val();  
                var jkartyil = $("#kartyil").val(); 
                var jkartcvv = $("#kartcvv").val().length;
                var hasError = false;

                // kontrollere başla

                if (jad < 6) {
                    $('#ad').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
                    hasError = true;
                    }

                if (jsoyad < 2) {
                    $('#soyad').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
                    hasError = true;
                    }

                if (jadres < 10) {
                    $('#adres').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
                    hasError = true;
                    }

                if (jeposta < 6) {
                    $('#eposta').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
                    hasError = true;
                    }

                if (jsehir == 0) {
                    $('#sehir').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
                    hasError = true;
                    }

                if (jtaksit == 20) {
                    $('#taksit').css('background', '#FF9494');
                    hasError = true;
                    }

                if (jkartisim < 6) {
                    $('#kartisim').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
                    hasError = true;
                    }

                if (jkartno < 15) {
                    $('#kartno').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
                    hasError = true;
                    }

                if (jkartay == 0) {
                    $('#kartay').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
                    hasError = true;
                    }

                if (jkartyil == 0) {
                    $('#kartyil').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
                    hasError = true;
                    }

                if (jkartcvv != 3) {
                    $('#kartcvv').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
                    hasError = true;
                    }

                if ($('#sozlesme').is(':checked')) {
                    hasError = false;

                }   else { 
                    $('#sozlesme').css('outline-color', 'red');
                    $('#sozlesme').css('outline-style', 'solid');
                    $('#sozlesme').css('outline-width', 'thin');
                    hasError = true; 
                    }

                if (!epostaReg.test(isEposta)) {
                    $('#eposta').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
                    hasError = true;
                    }

                if (hasError == true) {
                    $("#info").remove();
                    $("#ok").after('<span id="errorSpan" style="color:red;padding-left:5px;">Lütfen formu eksiksiz doldurunuz.</span>');
                    $("#errorSpan").delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
                    $('#ok').removeAttr("disabled");
                    return false;


                    } else {


                // form verilerini db ye at 

                var form_ad = $("#ad").val();  
                var form_soyad = $("#soyad").val();  
                var form_adres = $("#adres").val();  
                var form_eposta = $("#eposta").val();
                var form_sehir = $("#sehir").val(); 
                var form_taksit = $("#taksit").val(); 
                var form_telno = $("#telno").val(); 
                var form_cinsiyet = $("#cinsiyet").val(); 

                var dataString = 'ad='+ form_ad + 
                                 '&soyad=' + form_soyad + 
                                 '&adres=' + form_adres + 
                                 '&eposta=' + form_eposta + 
                                 '&sehir=' + form_sehir + 
                                 '&taksit=' + form_taksit + 
                                 '&telno=' + form_telno + 
                                 '&cinsiyet=' + form_cinsiyet;

                alert(dataString);

                JQuery.ajax({ 
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "form.php", 
                    data: dataString, 
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result){ 


                            if(result == 1) { 
                            alert(result); 

                            return false; } 

                            else {

                            $("#ok").after('<span id="errorSpan" style="color:red;padding-left:5px;">Lütfen formu eksiksiz doldurunuz.</span>');


                            }
                        } 
                    }); 

                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

and here is the code of the form.php

```
<?php

If (!isset($_POST['ad'])) {
    echo 0;
    }
    else {

$ad = $_POST['ad'];

If ($ad == "asdasd") {
    echo 1;
} else {

echo 0;
}

}
?>
```

I have read all the questions asked about this issue and try to apply all the solutions, but I'm stucked :/

Comment: you need to prevent the default action to prevent the submit from happening. http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: To add to my previous comment, ajax is asynchronous, meaning it may not be done before your submit function returns, thus possibly aborting the ajax request. Your return false inside of the ajax success handler does nothing.

Comment: Thanks Kevin B, I tried to use preventDefault but, not able to succeed. Do you have any idea where should i put that code?

Comment: It would go on the first line of your submit function, but you would have to add `event` to the `function()` so that it looks like `function(event)`. This will of course prevent the natural submit, you would have to find another way to make the natural submit happen, such as unbinding the submit event and re-triggering it.

Comment: Tried your advice, but not able to do it. Nothing happens, looks like Ajax form submisson never works.

Comment: After your `success` function, add an `error` function and alert the first three arguments.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#odeme").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
      
// form verilerini db ye at 
var form_ad = $("#ad").val();  
var dataString = 'ad='+ form_ad;
     
alert(dataString);
JQuery.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
url: "form.php", 
data: dataString, 
cache: false,
success: function(){ 
alert("ok");
        
}
      
error: function(xhr, status, err) {
alert(status + ": " + err);       
}
});           
});
});
</script>` I am using this code, and when i click the submit button nothing happens, it just submits the form manually.

Comment: @KevinB, you got any idea about what am i doing wrong when you compare my code with this tutorial; http://www.9lessons.info/2008/12/twitter-used-jquery-plug-in.html

Comment: In regards to your previous comment, do the event.preventDefault method that i mentioned earlier and you should find that an error is occuring. More than likely a syntax error.

Comment: I fixed it somehow, using event.preventDefault and changing some other stuff. It was likely a syntax error, as you mentioned. Thanks. @KevinB

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#odeme").submit(function() {

        //validation
        //and
        //ajax

        return false; //this suppresses default form submission behaviour 

    });
});
```

Comment: *"Right after the insert process completed successfully, I want the form to be submitted naturally."*

Comment: If you did that, then people with fast connections, would see the ">Lütfen formu ..." message for a maximum of a millisecond before the form submits and the page starts to refreshes. It would be more conventional (a) to allow/suppress the ajax action depending on the outcome of the validation, and return false from the outer function unconditionally to suppress form submission, or (b) not to perform any ajax and to allow/suppress form submission depending on the outcome of the validation.